# Proper way to store user information during the session in ExtJS MVC

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Where do I store user specific (session) information in an ExtJS MVC application?

Is it right to define a custom base controller that can contain an object with user specific info and use it in application?

Example:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.BaseController", {
    extend:  "Ext.app.Controller", 

    session:  Ext.create("MyApp.lib.UserSession"),

    init: function() {
      var me = this;

      me.session.init();

      /** some code **/
    },

    doSomething: function() {
      var me = this;

      var counter = me.session.get("counter"); 
    }

});
```

Comment: I modified your question slightly because it sounded too much like you were polling for opinions - something that is frowned upon at SO. I have an answer though below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it two ways depending on the application target.

My preferred method is using a LocalStorage proxy for my models I want to save locally, that way there is no change in how I interact with them in the application and it's a bit more handy when relaunching your application to set things up with out DB calls.

Alternatively, I create a global variable when starting the application. Inside the launch function do something like this.

```
var app = Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {     
        MyApp.model.User.load('profile', {
            scope: this,
            success: function(user) {
                // Setup the app space under your Application namespace
                // so you don't conflict with anything the the ExtJS framework has set
                MyApp.app.user = user;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way throughout your application, you'll have access to the current User's model through the variable `MyApp.user` So this can then be used in all areas of your application

```
var currentUserName = MyApp.app.user.get('name');
```

The downside of this is that you are introducing a global variable which is considered bad practise when it can be avoided.

I don't see there being anything wrong with constructing a base controller like you have suggested, but if you are doing it purely for access to the session variables you want to store I would suggest it's maybe a bit overkill.

Comment: Your way is more preferable in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you need to persist the data after page refresh you can use Ext.state.Manager.

Setup state manager with *Cookie* or *LocalStorage* provider during application **launch**:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());

// Shortcut for quick reference across the project, if MyApp.user is null - user is not authorized.
MyApp.user = Ext.state.Manager.get('user');
```

Save the data you need to persist for current user after authorization or other actions:

```
Ext.state.Manager.set('user', {
  first_name: 'John'
  last_name: 'Doe'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a few different apps that involved users with specific permission settings pulled from their session when they first start the app.

I struggled with doing this a few different ways, but I came to recognize that the user permission data all fit best within the MODEL context of MVC. With that in mind I decided to just put it all in a store.

This worked out nicely. If you create the store following the MVC guidelines, you can always call upon the user session data from anywhere in the app with `Ext.getStore('SessionStoreId')`

Answer (score 0):

I almost always create a State Manager class for these kind of things. You can also create singleton classes with your own custom code and include it in your app like so:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('MyApp.Util', 'app/util');
```

And do a require like so:

```
Ext.require('MyApp.Util.Class')
```

The class itself should be something like this:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.Util.Class", {
  singleton : true,
  options : {},

  myFunction: function(){}
});
```

That way you can put all your non-ExtJS like functionality in seperate classes.